# How to set attribute in yii model

Tags: yii, model

In my yii application. I write code as below:

```
OTP::model()->attributes['name'] = value;
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone please explain why its not working?

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to set attributes this way, the attribute should be marked as 'safe' in your validation rules (See: [Yii Model rules validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/))

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Class OTP{
  public function rules() {
    return array(
      array('name','safe')
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Safe is erquired only if using `setAttributes`, when assigning attribute manually it is not required.

Answer (score 2):

Setting value `$value` for attribute `$name` you just need:

> ```
> $obj = OTP::model();
> $obj->name = $value;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```
 $model->setAttribute("name","value");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define or extend a class, you can create class variables and methods in Yii just like you can in any other PHP system:

```
class Comment extends CActiveRecord {

    public $helperVariable;

    public function rules() { ... }
    ...
}
```

and then use them in the obvious way:

```
$var   = $model->helperVariable;

$rules = $model->rules();
```

This part everybody understands.

Answer (score 0):

if you have created model using gii you can set your attributes of your table's fields like below.

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'customer_first_name' => 'First Name',
            ...
            ...
        );
    }
```

in controller action put this code

```
$model = new Customer; // Use your model insterad of Customer
```

if you want to use it as a lable then just you need to put this code.

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'customer_first_name', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute in yii model

```
$obj = OTP::model();
$obj->name = $value;
```

Now if we pass this model to view then only these value will be displayed with ***name = $value***

```
$this->render('view',array('model'=>$obj));
```

How can we set **multiple value** ? 
Like so that value displayed be:

> name = value1 or name= value2 ...

```
 $obj->name= 'value1' 
  //  or
 $obj->name= 'value2'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$model = new OPT();
$model->attr = value
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?